# ADL using std types fails to find operator

Tags: c++, c++14

The following code fails to compile

```
namespace A {
using C = std::vector<std::string>;
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs, const C& rhs) {
    lhs << 5;
    return lhs;
}
}
int main()
{
    A::C f;
    std::cout << f;
    return 0;
}
```

with the error

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'A::C' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Obviously it cant find the << operator presumably due to considering C to be a class from the std namespace. Is there some way to ensure the compiler finds this operator or otherwise work around the problem?

Comment: Taking the operator out of the namespace should work.

Comment: `A::operator<<(std::cout, f);` But I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `A::C` is not a type definition, it's just an alias. The type lives in namespace `std`.

Comment: @interjay It is part of a large codebase where I would much prefer not to pollute the global scope if I can avoid it

Comment: @KerrekSB so could I then somehow define a class that for all intents and purposes originate in A but works exactly like std vector?

Comment: @Bomaz: `struct A : std::vector<int> {};`?

Comment: @KerrekSB ah, I found it using struct A : std::vector<int> {using std::vector<int>::vector;}; appears to mostly work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A::C` is just a type alias, and aliases are transparent. They don't "remember" where they came from. When we do argument-dependent lookup and figure out what the associated namespaces are, we only consider the associated namespaces of the *types* - not the alias that got us there. You can't just add associated namespaces to existing types. The specific associated namespace of `f` (which is of type `std::vector<std::string>`) is `std`, which doesn't have an `operator<<` associated with it. Since there's no `operator<<` found using ordinary lookup, nor is there one found using ADL, the call fails.

Now, I said you can't just add associated namespaces to existing types. But you can of course just create new types:

```
namespace A {
    struct C : std::vector<std::string> { };
}
```

or:

```
namespace A {
    // template parameters are also considered for associated namespaces
    struct S : std::string { };
    using C = std::vector<S>;
}
```

Comment: Note: For the purpose of this example that will work, but long-term you most likely will run into trouble by deriving from standard library types that were not designed for that.